# SQL query with date

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to use "date" in SQL, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Suggestions?

```
SELECT Name, ID, Town FROM Participants p, Towns t WHERE t.Date < '2012-05-19';
```

The answer I want is the name, ID and town where the date (from another table) is today or earlier.

Comment: What database are you using? How do you write date literals in it?

Comment: which RDBMS? e.g. oracle has `to_date('2012-05-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 0):

You've not joined your tables, and it's possible your database is taking the word date as a keyword?  If this is the case, try:

```
WHERE t.[Date] < '2012-05-09'
```

Comment: It is a cross join - a Cartesian product of the tables. You also seem to assume SQL Server.

Comment: I know it is a cross join, I just doubt that's what the OP intended!

Comment: Without more information from the OP, we can't tell for certain.

Comment: In some databases, this may be a _natural_ join, where columns of the same name and compatible types will be automatically used as the join condition.

Comment: Oracle. I should mention "Date" is not set as "date"... It's only varchar (10).

Comment: ... What I meant was that "Date" is only the name of the column. And when I try my query above I get the results, but with all the dates (even dates later than today).